# Datagridviewrow returning incorrect value of cell

Tags: vb.net, forms, datagridview

I have a simple DataGridView and I am trying to get the value of a cell when a button is clicked. When it is set to a variable it is incorrect but when I quick watch it it is correct. I don't see what is causing this?

```
 Private Sub btnUpdAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdAll.Click
        For Each r As DataGridViewRow In gvResults.Rows
            Dim x = r.Cells(1).Value
        Next
    End Sub
```

[image: Correct value in the cell]
[image: Variable gets this value]

Comment: You're looping through all the rows, so the value of `x` will change on each iteration.

Comment: Also, the value for `x` won't be set until you step past that assignment, so if that is the current line then you would expect `x` to contain the value from the previous row while the expression on the right would give the value from the current row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jmcilhinney said I was incorrectly declaring the variable inside the loop and resetting it every time. @shimrod, I wanted to get each row and update a single cell in every row like below.

```
 Private Sub btnUpdAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdAll.Click
        Dim x
        For Each r As DataGridViewRow In gvResults.Rows
            x = r.Cells(1).Value
            updateRecord(x)               
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

why loop if you want the value of one cell, the one you select.

i would use :

```
Private Sub btnUpdAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdAll.Click

   Dim row As DataGridViewRow = gvResults.CurrentRow

   Dim x as String= row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.toString()

End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub btnUpdAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdAll.Click

   Dim x As String = gvResults.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString()

End Sub
```